# "IndexError: list index out of range" for blackjack game

Tags: python, list, blackjack

I've learned the Basics of Python and currently trying to program my first little Python project: a basic blackjack game.

I'm currently running into

```
Index error: IndexError: list index out of range.
```

I have created a deck with 4 Set of cards:

```
deck = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11] * 4
```

I'm dealing the cards with a `dealing_cards` function:

```
def dealing_cards():
    """Dealing cards"""
player_cards.append(deck[random.randint(0, 52)])
player_cards.append(deck[random.randint(0, 52)])
dealer_cards.append(deck[random.randint(0, 52)])
dealer_cards.append(deck[random.randint(0, 52)])
```

If I'm running the code, it mostly works, however sometimes it raises the named `IndexError`:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why because I'm not popping the number from the deck list. The cards remain at their index and the `sum(deck)` always stays at 52.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, please don't use unnecessary acronyms unless they are _exceedingly_ common. Very few people are going to know that you mean "blackjack" by "BJ"

Comment: [`random.randint(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random%20randint#random.randint) generates a random integer _inclusive_ of both `a` and `b`. The highest index you can have with a list of length 52 is _51_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.randint(a, b)` returns an integer in the range `a` to `b`, inclusive.  It is an alias for `random.randrange(a, b+1)`.  So either use `random.randint(0, 51)`, or `random.randrange(0, 52)`.